# How to hide the label for the hidden field

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

I have been trying to hide the label of the hidden field defined in a model class using Django api. The CRUD operations of the model are managed by Django admin.

My model is

```
class RackForm(django.forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.fields['racktypeid'].widget = \
         forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'styles': 'display:none;'})
     ..... other initialization
```

The generated html source is given below

```
<div class="form-row racktypeid">


            <div>

                    **<label for="id_racktypeid" class="required">Rack Type:</label>**

                        **<input styles="display:none;" name="racktypeid" value="3" onchange="changeRackType(this);" type="hidden" id="id_racktypeid" />**




                    <p class="help">The physical type of rack as defined in the rack type list</p>

            </div>

    </div>
```

The field has been hidden but not the associated label. I have even tried using jQuery for it. I may be wrong with the syntax. If I am, please correct me if I am wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide label for RackForm rack type id label.
   $('#id_racktypeid, label[for="#id_racktypeid"]').hide()
    $('#id_racktypeid, label[for="#id_racktypeid"]').parent().hide()
  });
});
```

None of the options succeed. Is there anything I need to do hide the label of the hidden field?

Update: Eventually I chose to hide the entire div tag.

Comment: Don't include the # in the label[for="..."] selector.

Comment: Yes, the # is too much. Further this can be done with pure css: label[for="racktypeid"]{display:none;}

Comment: @arie: would i have to create a css file for this? I am sorry but I dont' understand..

Comment: Either you put it in a css file that you include in your template or you add it within a style-tag directly to the head of your page. In both cases the best way would probably be to create an extra_head-block in you base template that you can simply override/inherit in your actual template (see: http://ericholscher.com/projects/django-conventions/app).

Comment: See this template to get an idea what i mean: http://bit.ly/fQaix1

Answer (score -1):

Your problem stems from using `{{ form.as_p }}` or some other other shortcut function to render your form. Render the form yourself and you won't have this problem.

Also, in Django 1.3 there is an easier way to change the widget for a field, see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets